# Aplicação local(Pc) abrindo em navegador do ipad/iphone não mostra checkbox

Tags: javascript, css, iphone

Tenho uma aplicação rodando normalmente com wamp no computador, que usa html jquery css e php.

Porém ao abrir pelo navegador padrão do IOS (safari) usando ipad ou iphone através da rede local, o sistema não apresenta os checkbox da página.

Nestes casos existe alguma tipo de solução simples para que os checkboxes possam ser mostrados?

```css
input[type=radio].css-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1000;
  left: -1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

input[type=radio].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
  background-position: 0 -15px;
}

label.css-label {
  background-image: url(css/csscheckbox_e1eb6a6ff7155c99339c9d96211545f6.png);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="mudarItens" id="moveObjetos" class="css-checkbox">
```

Comment: Teremos que debugar seu código, a causa do problema pode ser varias. Insira uma tag <p> por exemplo entre os checkbox com um texto qualquer e veja se ele aparece no seu Ipad. Se aparecer eliminamos que a causa possa ser o servidor local. Me de um feedback do teste.

Comment: Se possível anexe o HTML das respectivas classes CSS que você anexou na pergunta.

Comment: Olá rafael tudo bem?! Obrigado pela resposta.Não apareceu usando a tag:
 
<pre><code>

<p><input type="radio" name="mudarItens" id="moveObjetos" class="css-checkbox" /></p>

</pre></code>

Comment: Nossa! mas porque todos esses níveis de tags?
Substitua esse trecho por isso <input type="radio" name="teste"> e me diga se funciona.

Comment: Essas tags eram para mostrar o código aqui na page separadamente, mas por algum motivo não funcionou. 

Voltando ao assunto rafael, o <input type="radio" name="teste"> apareceu! porém se aplicar a classe "css-checkbox" desaparece novamente.

Esse checkbox é estilizado com uma imagem, roda normal pelo computador porém pelo ipad/iphone desaparece.

Comment: Bom, já sabemos que não é problema das tags... Você está usando MediaQuery? se não estiver aconselho que você faça o debug do seu CSS para encontrar o erro, da seguinte maneira, você dá um CTRL + X nessa parte do código e vai adicionando linha a linha, aonde parar de funcionar você sabe que está o problema. Me envie qual foi a linha que deu problema.

Comment: Você poderia criar um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), assim nós poderíamos ver esse código funcionando. (Dica: use `"backticks"` ( ` ) para marcação de códigos.)